# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when using CQLSSTableWriter

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am using `CQLSSTableWriter` in an application which prepares sstables for bulk load into Cassandra 2.1.2 using sstableloader.

"Sometimes" I encounter this exception in the application's output:

```
14:23:58.694 [Thread-4] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_area_cell1/sensordata-packets_area_cell1-tmp-ka-318-CompressionInfo.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_area_cell1/sensordata-packets_area_cell1-ka-318-CompressionInfo.db
14:23:58.695 [Thread-4] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_area_cell1/sensordata-packets_area_cell1-tmp-ka-318-Data.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_area_cell1/sensordata-packets_area_cell1-ka-318-Data.db
Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 132385
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.append(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:196)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.sortCells(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.maybeSortCells(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:125)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.access$1100(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:44)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns$CellCollection.iterator(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:622)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamily.iterator(ColumnFamily.java:476)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamily.getColumnStats(ColumnFamily.java:429)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.append(SSTableWriter.java:225)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter$DiskWriter.run(SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter.java:215)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at dk.company.commons.app.CliCommandList$1.execute(CliCommandList.java:50)
    at dk.company.commons.app.CliCommandList.invoke(CliCommandList.java:80)
    at dk.company.ais.store.Main.main(Main.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 132385
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.append(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:196)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.sortCells(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:167)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.maybeSortCells(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:125)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.access$1100(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:44)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns$CellCollection.iterator(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:622)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamily.iterator(ColumnFamily.java:476)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamily.getColumnStats(ColumnFamily.java:429)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.append(SSTableWriter.java:225)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter$DiskWriter.run(SSTableSimpleUnsortedWriter.java:215)
14:24:45.763 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-Index.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-Index.db
14:24:45.763 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-Filter.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-Filter.db
14:24:45.765 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-Digest.sha1 to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-Digest.sha1
14:24:45.765 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-Statistics.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-Statistics.db
14:24:45.766 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-TOC.txt to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-TOC.txt
14:24:45.766 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-CompressionInfo.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-CompressionInfo.db
14:24:45.767 [Thread-3] DEBUG o.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils - Renaming /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-tmp-ka-320-Data.db to /mnt/datasstables-generated/2006/05/sensordata/packets_id/sensordata-packets_id-ka-320-Data.db
```

I remain yet to figure out whether "sometimes" is always at the same place in my input files; or whether the exception is triggered more unpredictably. The dataset is quite large - so it takes a while to reproduce. The example above occured after 9 hours of processing raw input from files.

Has someone else seen this - or knows how to resolve it?

**UPDATE**: I have filed a bug report: 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8978.

Comment: Are you using multiple CQLSSTableWriter instances concurrently?

Comment: No. But I have multiple instances of CQLSSTableWriter called from the same thread (to store data to multiple tables/cf).

Comment: I'm not sure if its a good idea to write to multiple tables of the same CF at the same time. Even from the same thread. I don't think thats a regular Cassandra use case, which could be an issue as the writer is basically just using the internal C* engine classes.

Comment: Hmmm... good input. Thank you. I will investigate along these lines. Although I think it is normal C* practice to have multiple tables with redundant data for lookups by different keys.

Comment: I have changed my code to have only one CQLSSTableWriter going at any time; but I still see sporadic ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptions.